How can I save information about which build agent ran a job and then re-use that later
In Azure Devops, let's say you have three self-hosted agents (A1, A2, A3) that run on the same Windows Server and they are all part of the Default agent pool. When we build our code, we have a build stage and a release stage. These can be separated by many hours and is there not run one after the other.
Let's say agent A1 build the artifact. Now in a later stage I want to deploy the artifact to a customer. For it to work it needs access to the correct files and artifact. The problem is now, that my release runs at a later stage, and if agent A1 is now occupied it will pick up the next available agent, e.g. A2, but this agent is not able to find the artifact because it is in a different folder, and the release jobs fails.
So, my question is:
Is there a way to use the same agent for the release stage?

You don't need to have a dependency on a specific build agent.
If the stages run in the same pipeline you can use build artifacts to share artifacts between different jobs or stages.
If you need to share artifacts between different pipelines use pipeline artifacts instead.
Working example using build artifacts (same pipeline):
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: Stage A
  jobs:
  - job: PublishArtifact
    displayName: Publish Artifact
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Creating dummy artifact..."
        echo "Hello, World!" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dummy.txt
      displayName: Create Dummy Artifact
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        artifactName: drop
      displayName: Publish artifact

- stage: B
  displayName: Stage B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: DownloadArtifact
    displayName: Download Artifact
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
      displayName: Download artifact
    - script: |
        echo "Displaying dummy artifact..."
        cat $(Agent.TempDirectory)/drop/dummy.txt
      displayName: Output Artifact Content

Running the build, you can see the generated artifact by clicking on 1 artifact:


As @Rui Jarimba has suggested, we strongly recommended you use the pipeline artifacts tasks to shared build artifact files between jobs, stages and pipelines. The build artifacts tasks also can do these things, however, the pipeline artifacts tasks are the newer tasks and have faster performance.

If you still want the subsequent release stage can use the same agent as build stage, you can try like as below:

Within the same agent pool, each agent has the unique name. In the pipeline, you can use the predefined variable "Agent.Name" to get the name of the agent which the current job is running on.

In the job of build stage, you can use the logging command "SetVariable" to set an output variable and pass the agent name as its value. Then you can pass the output variable to the subsequent release stage which dependsOn the build stage.

In the release stage, you can map the output variable as a stage-level variable. Then use this variable to set the 'demands' of the 'pool' key.


Below are the example as reference.

Use the same agent at the stage-level. With below configuration, all the jobs (releaseJob1 and releaseJob2) in release stage will use the same agent from Default pool as buildJob in build stage.
. . .

pool: Default

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: buildJob
    steps:
    . . .

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Show Infor'
      name: agentInfor
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Write-Host "Agent.Name = $(Agent.Name)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AgentName;isoutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"

- stage: release
  dependsOn: build
  variables:
    preAgentName: $[ stageDependencies.build.buildJob.outputs['agentInfor.AgentName'] ]
  pool:
    name: Default
    demands: Agent.Name -equals $(preAgentName)
  jobs:
  - job:  releaseJob1
    . . .

  - job:  releaseJob2
    . . .


Use the same agent on the particular job.  With below configuration:

The releaseJob1 in release stage will use the same agent from Default pool as buildJob in build stage.
The releaseJob2 in release stage will use any available agent from Default pool.

. . .

pool: Default

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: buildJob
    steps:
    . . .

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Show Infor'
      name: agentInfor
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Write-Host "Agent.Name = $(Agent.Name)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AgentName;isoutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"

- stage: release
  dependsOn: build
  variables:
    preAgentName: $[ stageDependencies.build.buildJob.outputs['agentInfor.AgentName'] ]
  jobs:
  - job:  releaseJob1
    pool:
      name: Default
      demands: Agent.Name -equals $(preAgentName)
    . . .

  - job:  releaseJob2
    . . .





I know you're just trying answer the OP's question, but doing exactly what he asked is a complicated workaround for a very simple problem :-)

BTW thanks for the feedback regarding the tasks performance, didn't know about that.

OP wanted to use the same agent because he couldn't think of another way to solve his/her problem. You, as a support engineer for Azure DevOps, should be promoting best practices and guiding less knowledgeable users towards the right tools (in this case tasks) in Azure DevOps.
